# Ads only show on android emulator

Tags: android, adblock

I have tried integrating mobclix and a admob. Both of them dont not show up on my android phone. They show up fine on the emulator though. I was thinking it could be ad blockers because I bought a used rooted phone. How do I tell if I have ad blockers? If I do, how do I get rid of them? What other things could be causing this?

Comment: Michael, please accept some of the answers to your earlier questions, or people are likely to stop answering your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Connect your mobile phone to your pc(using USB), and watch the `LogCat` when you run the app on the mobile, the `AdMob` library prints on the `LogCat`, informations about pulling ads from the internet, if you have ad blocked phone, you will notice in the `LogCat` some information about `Can't Connect to Server` or equivalent, in some cases it tells you, there is no enough ads to show in your app, in this case go to your account on `AdMob` and activate `Google Ad Sense` in the `Application Settings`..

---

`LogCat` window can be found under `Window` menu in `Eclipse IDE`, under sub category for `Android`. or read this answer to show `LogCat` [running logcat on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051521/running-logcat-on-eclipse/7051602#7051602)

Best Regards

Comment: I google the error I got and found out it is the ad blocker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654172/admob-connection-refused. So do you know how to get rid of ad blocker?

Comment: i think you must remove the ad blocker from the system, search in your applications list in the mobile , if found just un-install it

Comment: I cant find an ad blocker anywhere.

Comment: i found those two threads for removing AdBlocker, i hope it will help you:

1- http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-rooting-roms-hacks/56255-myn-rls5-remove-ad-blocker.html

2- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=741435

`The summary:  goto the market download the app adfree...load it up and then click revert hosts file (that will remove any of the adblocker stuff)....reboot then you got your ads back`